# Не работает click по элементу после append

Tags: jquery, javascript

Почему не работает?

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
  alert("qeqqe");
});

var item = '<div class="item">qeqqe</div>'

$('.wrapper').append(item);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите вот так:

```
$(".wrapper").on("click", ".item", function() {
    alert("qeqqe");
});
```

[Ссылка](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) для самостоятельного изучения.

Comment: Фурыкает :)

Comment: ну да, поспешил немного, забыл про body :)